# SubArray With Maximum Xor

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have given a Array A i have to find a subarray such that it's xor value is maximum.

I am using **Trie**.But i getting Time Limit Exceeded Error in some Test Cases.

My Time Complexity is **O(N*30*2)**

**Constraints:**

```
2 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
0 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^9
```

My Code: Trie:

```
  static  class Batman{

    Batman[] N;
    long val;

    Batman(){
      N = new Batman[2];
      val=-1;
    }
  }
```

Insert Code:

```
 public static void insert(int curr){

       Batman temp = Root;
      int[] A = new int[max+1];
      int currs = curr;
      for(int i=0;i<=max;i++)
      {
          A[i] = curr%2;
          curr/=2;
      }

       for(int i=max;i>=0;i--){

            if(temp.N[A[i]]==null){
                temp.N[A[i]] = new Batman();
            }

            temp = temp.N[A[i]];

       }
       temp.val = currs;


  }
```

My Query Code:

```
  public static long google(int curr){
        long yes=0;

          Batman temp = Root;
          int[] A = new int[max+1];
          for(int i=0;i<=max;i++)
          {
              A[i] = curr%2;
              curr/=2;
          }

          for(int i=max;i>=0;i--){

              int t = 1-A[i];

              if(temp.N[t]!=null){    
                  temp = temp.N[t];
              }else
                  temp = temp.N[A[i]];


          }




        return temp.val;
  }
```

Code To Get Ans:

```
insert(0);
xor=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    xor^=A[i];

    insert(xor);
    long y = google(xor);

    y = y^xor;

    ans = Math.max(ans,y);

}
```

How Can I make it Faster like a Flash.

Comment: What competition is this from?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom [Link](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2683)

Comment: Thanks @Sunny. So that's from a competition that was held in 2009. And you're working through those problems for your own benefit. Sounds fair to me, and could be useful to others. :-) Would you be so kind as to edit that link into the question itself?